# Get specific column from a collection ActiveRecord objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I extract a list of IDs from a returned ActiveRecord results without re-querying the `ID` column alone?
For exmaple:

```
people = People.all
people.get_ids #Returns an array of IDS
```

My current solution is to loop through `people` and get the ID manually(which isn't very elegant, IMHO)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **pluck** method:

e.g. `People.pluck(:id)`

Refer http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck

Fetching using pluck would be better compared to the process of fetching the same after taking all results.

Hope that helps..

Answer (score 6):

You can use `map` method

```
all_ids = people.map(&:id) #[1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ids = People.all.map(&:id)
```

This code will return array of ids